# Mechanism to sync mail accounts between Mac and iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, email

Is there a way for me to create an account using my Mac's Mail app and have the account sync over to my iPhone or vice versa? I have iCloud setup on both my Mac and iPhone, but I don't see the accounts added on one device syncing over to the other.

Comment: When using IMAP mail accounts you have to do nothing: this is already a "sync" method.
Only POP is not synced. See other answer.
Lex

Comment: Correct and seems quite dull to me. As usual if use icloud all syncs up pretty well. If you try and use something different, no luck. Why would you want to use something different than icloud? They'll probably come up with some corporate bs about security or stuff.

Comment: Jozef and Össi have got the question right. I have tried in vain to find the answer for a while as I find it very amateur to have to enter again all email account settings whenever you have to configure a new IOS device.

Answer (score 11):

No.

(if what you want is a way to configure an account once on a device and have the configuration automagically transferred to other devices.)

Comment: -1 unhelpful, since at some point the answer was "Yes" - and it even happened automatically. See @calion's answer.

Answer (score 7):

This was possible in Mountain Lion and before, through iTunes. Unfortunately Apple has deprecated its Syncserver service, and so now you have to set up each account separately on each device. Frustrating, I agree.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. I swear that sometime in the past my accounts popped up magically in my iPhone but couldn't remember how or why that happened, nor why it's not happening now. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to synchronize email accounts between Macs. This is what the [iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085) is for. Activating it will sync over all of your accounts (those listed in the Mac Accounts settings). One problem is that it is an all or none setting.

However this doesn't help synchronize email accounts between Mac and iOS.

Comment: How does this work? Keychain syncs passwords, not accounts, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Calion iCloud Keychain does sync accounts as well, but only between Macs. So my answer is actually incorrect.

Comment: What's worse is that Keychain doesn't seem to auto-fill passwords when you are creating Mail accounts in iOS.

Comment: @JozefLegény why don't you change your answer, if you say it's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. However, the [Apple Configurator app](https://apps.apple.com/be/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?l=fr&mt=12) helps creating a .mobileconfig file that makes account creation much easier (basically you enter all the settings on your Mac then import them onto the iOS devices).

Answer (score -4):

You can use IMAP/POP3

On Mac you can add IMAP/POP3 account from `System Preferences > Internet Accounts`

1. Open Internet Accounts
2. Click plus icon on left bottom corner
3. If it's iCloud mail, Gmail or Microsoft Exchange account click the option respectively, otherwise select "Add Other Account..." from the bottom of the list
4. Follow trough the guided account setup, and in the end of setting it up (if it asks) check the Email syncing option.
5. You can get the mail server info from your email provider, but most of them use `mail.provider.tld` (eg. mail.google.com / mail.ipage.com) domain for the mail server

   On iDevice (iPhone in this case) open Settings > Contacts, Calendar & Email > Add new account and follow the instructions inserting the same credentials as you gave when adding account to Mac. This way the mail application will fetch the email from the server on both devices, and sync it.
   Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the question is not asking about syncing the actual emails with IMAP, but syncing the account SETUP, so it doesn't have to be entered all over again. This does not seem possible.